# Why is Math.random being outperformed by crypto.getRandomValues?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, random

I've re-implemented `Math.random()` using `crypto.getRandomValues` with a "entropy pool" scheme to reduce the overhead of calls to `crypto.getRandomValues`. On my computer (x86_64 Windows Chrome) this seems to be about 260% faster than `Math.random()`. I find this surprising because I was under the impression that Chrome implements the latter using the blazingly fast xorshift128+ PRNG, which should be orders of magnitude faster than whatever CSPRNG is being used under the hood for the former.

```
class EntropyPool {
    #entropy; #index
    constructor(poolSize = 1024) {
        this.#entropy = new Uint32Array(poolSize)
        this.#index = 0
        crypto.getRandomValues(this.#entropy)
    }
    next() {
        const value = this.#entropy[this.#index++]
        if (this.#index === this.#entropy.length) {
            crypto.getRandomValues(this.#entropy)
            this.#index = 0
        }
        return value
    }
}

const pool = new EntropyPool()

function random() {
    return pool.next() / 4294967296
}
```

Comment: Could you share the benchmark too? Running a (non-sensical) micro-benchmark doing just `n += random()` in a loop, I get 2x faster for Math.random() on Chrome 101 and x18 on Firefox 100.

Comment: @Kaiido Here's the benchmark. Accumulating the result in a variable didn't change the outcome for me. I get around 160M op/s for `Math.random` and around 405M for `random`. https://jsbench.me/p1l3huwkoe/1

Answer (score 2):

(V8 developer here.)

**The first rule of microbenchmarks is that they will mislead you.**

One of the most common pitfalls is to not use the result of the operation under test, which allows optimizing compilers to optimize out dead code, and you'll be left measuring (nearly) empty loops. Sometimes this works only for one of the variants you're comparing, which will give hugely skewed results.

If you force a use of the result by changing the test to:

```
let result = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    result += Math.random();
}
if (result > 100) throw "bad";
```

then you'll see that `Math.random` is actually faster than your custom `random` (I'm seeing 642K vs 507K ops/sec).

In other words: the premise of this question is incorrect, `Math.random` is *not* being outperformed by `crypto.getRandomValues`. It's just that the particular way in which your microbenchmark uses the latter is more amenable to dead-code elimination when the results aren't used.

**To avoid being misled by microbenchmarks, you really have to inspect generated code and/or trace other engine internals.** If you don't have the time or expertise to do that, then don't use microbenchmarks. Instead, implement A/B comparisons in your real app, and see if you can measure differences there. If you can, then you also immediately know that they are relevant for your app. If you can't (e.g. because they're too small in comparison to the rest of the app), then you know that they don't matter. Profiling is a great way to figure out where the greatest potential for impact is.

Comment: Sorry, you're wrong. At least on my machine. https://jsfiddle.net/m71auz39 I get ~54 fps for `pool.next()` and ~40 fps for `Math.random()`

Comment: @Chris_F I disagree that coming up with a new microbenchmark makes the analysis of what happened in the previous microbenchmark "wrong".

Comment: Math.random() is slower than my crypto.getRandomValues entropy pool. That's the fact, Jack. Your "analysis" as you are calling it didn't refute or explain that in any way.

Comment: @Chris_F well, if you call `random` less than 1024 times, then your entropy pool will unnecessarily compute further values. `Math.random` will probably only be called once in the average application and rarely in a hot loop ... So I guess you can pretty much get whatever conclusion you want by calling `random()` somewhere between 1 and 1024 times (or even more often, as in your benchmark). (off-topic: If you want other people to help you, I doubt that you'll get far in that tone)

Comment: @Chris_F and FWIW one can easily influence the "fps" rate shown by leaving the tab and reopening it again, as that will halt execution of the loop but will not reset the start, so with a little back and forth between tabs one can show any fps rate (managed to get it down from 40fps to 1fps) ;)

Comment: @JonasWilms I didn't write the benchmark of the year, just to point out when a dev is trying to gaslight me. Math.random() is still slower on Chrome Win-x64 than crypto.getRandomValues with a cache to amortize the relatively expensive call.